# How do I stop Pandas Dataframe read_json method convert my epoch to human readable string

Tags: json, string, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I use `to_json` method to serialize my dataframe, the content is look like this:

```
"1467065160244362165":"1985.875","1467065161029130301":"1985.875","1467065161481601498":"1985.875","1467065161486508221":"1985.875"
```

How do I stop the read_json method convert my epoch value from `1467065160244362165` to something like `2016-06-28 06:57:23.786726222`.
This is how i call read_json:

```
data = pd.read_json(remote_result_fullpath, convert_dates=False)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For me works:

```
import pandas as pd

#added {} to file
remote_result_fullpath = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/84444599/file.json'

data = pd.read_json(remote_result_fullpath, 
                    convert_dates=False, #dont convert columns to dates 
                    convert_axes=False, #dont convert index to dates
                    typ='series') #if need convert output to Series

print (data)
1467065160244362165    1985.875
1467065161029130301    1985.875
1467065161481601498    1985.875
1467065161486508221    1985.875

print (data.dtypes)
dtype: float64
float64
```

If need strings add `dtype`:

```
data = pd.read_json(remote_result_fullpath, 
                    convert_dates=False, 
                    convert_axes=False,
                    typ='series',
                    dtype='object')

print (data)
1467065160244362165    1985.875
1467065161029130301    1985.875
1467065161481601498    1985.875
1467065161486508221    1985.875

print (data.dtypes)
dtype: object
object

print (data.index)
Index(['1467065160244362165', '1467065161029130301', '1467065161481601498',
       '1467065161486508221'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: This solution is no longer up to date. The `read_json` no longer takes those arguments.